# selenium python seleccion ccs

Tags: python, selenium

Dentro de una tabla con diferentes `links`, quiero dar **click** en uno en especifico que al inspeccionar el elemento me muestra lo siguiente, estoy trabajando con **`Python`**:

```html
<a tabIndex="-1" class="SItreeText" style="WORD-WRAP: normal; WHITE-SPACE: nowrap" href="#" shape="">Ventas Diarias</a>
```

las maneras en que trate son:

```
diver.find_element_by_class_name('SItreeText').click()
diver.find_element_by_css_selector('SItreeText').click()
```

ninguna  me funciona, alguien tendrá alguna idea? 
muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Lo que has escrito está bien, en ocasiones la etiqueta en la que estás haciendo click, no está visible en la página (pero si en el código html) y tienes que hacer que se visibilice en el navegador para poder acceder a él.

Si no es eso puedes probar también:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="SItreeText"]').click()
```

Prueba primero sin el click, para ver si te está devolviendo el elemento, y si te lo devuelve haz click.

Answer (score 0):

Quizás el elemento que quiere acceder esta muy adentro del [DOM](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) y se necesita el elemento que lo tiene comprendido para acceder a el.

Por ejemplo :

```
    <div class ='hola2'>
        <p>
            <a tabIndex="-1" class="SItreeText" style="WORD-WRAP: normal; WHITE-SPACE: nowrap" href="#" shape="">Ventas Diarias</a>
        </p>

    </div>
```

En ese ejemplo se puede acceder de varias maneras:

*tag:*

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('hola2').find_element_by_tag_name('p').find_element_by_tag_name('a').click()
```

*clase:*

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('hola2').find_element_by_tag_name('p').find_element_by_class_name('SItreeText').click()
```

*javascript:*

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('SItreeText')[0].click();")
```

*En tu caso, el último ejemplo debería funcionar.*